# How to override needed messages from core messages in yii2

Tags: internationalization, yii2, translation

In yii2, i want to override some core messages translation, example:
in @yii/messages/vi/yii.php, has key => translated message:

```
'Update' => 'Sửa'
```

but in my application, i want to change this as:

```
'Update' => 'Cập nhật'
```

I have created the file: @app/messages/vi/yii.php, has only one the message which need to override:

```
return [
    'Update' => 'Cập nhật'
];
```

in my main.php config, I added this to components:

```
'i18n' => [
      'translations' => [
            'yii' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@app/messages'
           ],
      ],
],
```

It works but just only for the override messages, others of core don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should copy yii.php from core to `@common/messages/<your language>/yii.php` and edit it. It should be work stable.

Comment: Thank for your quick solution, but if the core message will be updated so we will lose them. I think we should just override only the needed messages, not copy all from core.

Comment: Core update, then current message not update. That's not effect your current project. So it work stable.

Answer (score 0):

Try somehing like this

```
'i18n'=>[

                    'yii'=>[
                        'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                        'basePath' => "@vendor/yiisoft/yii2/messages",
                        'sourceLanguage' => 'en_US', // put your language here
                        'fileMap' => [
                            'yii'=>'yii.php',
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't help me, file map is just for mapping Category to physical file.

Answer (score 0):

Might be outdated thread but I'm putting this in case someone hits this in a search results as I did.

This works out for me :

```php
// get the default translation file for desired language
$yii = require \Yii::getAlias('@vendor/yiisoft/yii2/messages/az/yii.php');

// just override what ever you want
return yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge( $yii,
[
   'update' => 'myUpdateString',
   // ... and so on 
]);
```